# If you add a rendering to a SXA cache settings item will it break personalization

Tags: sxa, personalization, caching

As the title says.

If you enable caching for a rendering in SXA using a CacheSetting item e.g. under

```
/sitecore/content/My Client/EMEA/My Website/Presentation/Cache Settings
```

Will this prevent personalization from working for this rendering? The rendering in question is the SXA `Link List` and in some places I need to personalize it and in others not. I'd like to cache where possible.

Using Sitecore 9 and SXA 1.8.